# LED needs a minimum current or minimum voltage to operate in forward bias

Tags: led, circuit-analysis, battery-operated, photodiode

I want to wire up an IR LED on a battery. I've seen many tutorials telling me that I should add a resistor, but none says what resistor to use to maximize battery life. So a 680ohm resistor will do the job of powering up the LED, but will a 47k resistor do the job too and keep the current still running (which will be more beneficial for the battery)?

I wonder if the LED (and all the diodes) need a minimum current, or a minimum voltage to operate, because I want to know how will adding one more diode in series or in parallel affect my choice of a resistor.

Also is my thinking correct? Say I have a 9V battery and a 0.7V drop LED. This means that if I place a resistor in series, the voltage drop through the resistor will always be 8.3V.
So the current through both the resistor and the LED will be determined by the current through the resistor R which will be 8.3V / R.

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: I haven't bought any yet...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I efficiently drive an LED?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55823/how-can-i-efficiently-drive-an-led)

Comment: I think this question [How can I efficiently drive an LED?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55823/how-can-i-efficiently-drive-an-led) will tell you what you want to know about LEDs.

Comment: What @Ignacio meant is that datasheets are publicly available on the Internet. Just Google your IR LED part number or code and you'll get the datasheet. It will tell you everything about the IR LED. It may take a while for you to learn how to read a datasheet, but once you do it, it will become your primary source of info about the parts you will be working with.

Comment: Here's [one example of a random IR LED datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LED/YSL-R531FR2C-F1.pdf)

Comment: @Ricardo yes, this one does not have a graph like the one I can see in the answer. and indeed from the available shops, it seems this is the IR LED i'll be sold to, and they didn't provide a part number @#$

Comment: I know what you mean! But they may tell you what the part number is if you ask them specifically, even if they don't show it on their website. If they don't tell you or don't know, then find a better shop.

Comment: @Ricardo it is the only one in my town that sells 850nm  ir leds.. the rest at 940nm :(

Comment: I know what you mean!! There are about 6 shops in the town I live, none of which is worth going. So I do all my electronic components shopping online (domestic not international, though). The packages get home in a couple of days and just travel a couple of states over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking a look at a [datasheet](http://www.lumex.com/specs/OED-EL-1L2.pdf) for a popular IR LED, the Lumex OED-EL-1L2, we can see the IR light output vs. current curve:

[image]

So if you only give it 1mA, it gives you 0.2mW/sr radiant intensity. At 20mA, you get 10mW/sr radiant intensity.

So, to maximize battery life, you should use the minimum current that will produce a light intensity that your circuit can (with an appropriate safety margin accounting for all the things that can change, including LED aging and temperature) work with.

If the sr unit used for the [radiant intensity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_intensity) is unfamiliar- that's the SI unit of solid angle, so it's power per unit of solid angle.

[image]

Comment: Worth noting from Spehro's graph and numbers : 20x the current = 50x the brightness, so low currents are relatively inefficient. You get more IR power from your battery by driving at higher current (say 20ma) and saving power by shortening the pulses instead.