# 10 ohm resistor instead of voltage step down? 12V to 9V

Tags: led, resistors

I need to power an LED which is rated for 9V and about 300mA. I have a 12V battery pack and I can't add anything to step down the voltage. I figured that if I use a 10 ohm resistor the 12V shouldn't be able to damage my LED and I won't need the voltage step down and power the 9V LED off the 12V. Is this correct?

Comment: Data sheet link for the LED is needed.

Comment: I don't have that, I gave all the info I have on this LED. I measured and it draws 300mA, it says 9V written on the chip.

Comment: Then it can't be answered accurately and with assurance.

Comment: I don't think there are actually LEDs that you can put 9 V across without destroying them. I'm thinking that your "LED" must actually be a lamp that contains an LED as well as some other electronics that make it able to run off 9 V.

Comment: There are LED chips with multiple emitters in series. This might be a chip with three white LEDs in series, but without a datasheet we will never know...

Comment: +1 on that Andy said. Decent chance it would work though but impossible to tell for sure.

Comment: Four forward-biased 1 A diodes (like 1N4007) in series will do the job.

Comment: Your resistor will dump 900 mW, so use one with a proper wattage to not melt anything.

Comment: "Led" as these for 9V : Not "Led only" but yellow phosphor LES , unless error, https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-53269-0 https://www.bridgelux.com/sites/default/files/resource_media/DS58_Rev%20B%20Gen2%20SMD%202835%201W%209V%20Data%20sheet.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I efficiently drive an LED?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55823/how-can-i-efficiently-drive-an-led)

Comment: Post a picture of the LED if you don't have a datasheet.

Comment: Notionally it SHOULD work. Operate from 9V supply with a say 300 mA current limit. If it drops 9V then a 12V supply and 10 Ohm resistor should work

Comment: @TannerSwett See the link I added in OP question.

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer: NO.

Long answer: you start off with what you are calling a 12 V battery. However, a battery does not give a steady voltage. If it's a 12 V lead acid battery, it will do 11.5 up to 14.5 V (very much depending on the battery manufacturer and technology). All types of batteries do this, li-ion for example are often called 3.3 V, but often operate 3.0 up to 4.5 V, so four in series could be a 12 V battery, but will output 12 V to 18 V depending on charge level.

Straight away this causes a problem. A 12 V down to 9 V drop at a constant current is easy to calculate. But you aren't doing that, you're doing a variable voltage input down to 9 V drop, which will get complicated, so it will be a lot easier to do a DC-DC converter (as that's what you'll be doing anyway with a changing voltage input).

And now we get onto the next question: what's happening in this LED. You have not supplied a datasheet. As has been mentioned, LEDs will not be taking 9 V across it. It will most likely have some kind of constant current souce inside the LED, but we don't know for sure and so we can't tell you the best way to reduce the voltage to 9 V. The datasheet would give you a voltage input range, and that may make you life easy (if it's a large input range) or more tricky. But if it has a large input range, the voltage will vary to keep the same power: higher voltage lower current, same power and the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you said, then yes.

But for practical purposes, it is not ideal. If your battery is higher than 12V, say 14.5V of a charging car/bike/cart system, then your going to get a higher current draw and voltage drop. As the battery drains it will drop voltage and thus current and thus brightness. The latter is typically not an issue, just an annoyance, but the former is a problem. Too much current will burn out the leds or at least reduce their lifespan.

You can use some basic diodes like three 1n400x to provide a more constant voltage drop (typically 0.7V each) and then a smaller resistor like 3.5 to 5 ohms to regulate the current (*I'm assuming your led does not have a built in current regulator*). This should result in less than 300 mA at 12V, which should protect you if the voltage is higher than 12V and provide a longer life for the leds.

Answer (score 0):

The resistor will work fine, but its value should be calculated to not exceed the maximum LED current at the maximum fully charged battery voltage.

> I can't add anything to step down the voltage

However, if your problem is running out of space in the enclosure, the resistor may not be the best solution because it will dissipate about 1W, so it will be pretty large and need cooling. Note the power rating of resistors is at their maximum temperature, so if you dissipate 1W in an 1W resistor, it will heat to about 150°C. Since your LED will have a heat sink, a much better option is a cemented (square body cross section) resistor and epoxy it on the heat sink. If your LEDs are on a PCB which is mounted on a heat sink, you can also use SMD resistors and transfer heat to the heat sink through the PCB with vias. But, again, they won't be tiny.

So the resistor will not solve your lack of space issue.

But... a constant current buck driver could, in fact, use less space, and also require a smaller heatsink since it won't have to dissipate power wasted in the resistor.